# How can I keep track of a username for a current user in a program?

Tags: java, authentication

I am working on a school project that is being coded in Java and interacts with a My SQL Database.

I have already gotten the login screen to determine if the username and password is correct and if so, move to the main screen. What I would like to do now is keep track of the user that has logged in so that I can reference it in other classes. I created a currentUser class that consists of the following.

```
public class CurrentUser {
  public String loggedInUser; 

  CurrentUser(String user){
      this.loggedInUser = user;
}


  public String getCurrentUser(){
      return this.loggedInUser;
} 

  public void setCurrentUser(String user){
     this.loggedInUser = user;
}   
 }
```

In my login application, in the area after username and password has been confirmed, I put the following.

```
void handleLogIn(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException {

// verify login and send to main screen
String userName = username.getText();   
String passWord = password.getText();

boolean notFound = true;
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sqlExecute = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName = " + "'" + userName + "'" + " AND password=" + "'" + passWord + "'";
Query.makeQuery(sqlExecute);
ResultSet result = Query.getResult();
while (result.next() && notFound){

    //System.out.print(result.getString("userName"));
    //System.out.print(result.getString("password")); 
    if (userName.equals(result.getString("userName")) && passWord.equals(result.getString("password"))){
        notFound = false; 
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainmenu.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        currentUser current = new currentUser("userName");
    }

}
```

userName refers to the variable that contains the userName that has just been confirmed. I'm getting the error "currentUser is not public in currentUser". How could I go about fixing this issue? Any points in the correct direction or resources would be very helpful!

Comment: Where excatly do you get the error? How are you trying to get your variable `userName` and where is it set?

Comment: I get the error before even compiling, my IDE is warning me it's not valid. The variable userName is set in the same block which is called when someone clicks "log in". userName refers to the username that they typed into the box before pressing log in, and at the time of where I am trying to call it in the current user object, it has already been verified to be the correct username!

Comment: I can include that part of the code as well if that would help give a clearer picture!

Comment: Yes, you must include the code that is causing the error as well as the full error message

Comment: I recommend you rename `String currentUser` so it does not mirror the name of your class. Right now it's a bit confusing.

Comment: I have added the beginning part of the code, and I also changed String currentUser to String loggedInUser for clarity!

Comment: Agree with @AnilM. In fact you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: That makes sense. I will adjust accordingly!

Comment: At which line of your code are you getting your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your constructor. Maybe try to set the constructor to public:

```
    public CurrentUser(String user) {
        this.loggedInUser = user;
    }
```

Comment: That fixed it!! Thank you!

Comment: @Cassie: really?

Comment: At the time, I thought it did. It fixed the error at hand but it didn't accomplish what I wanted, but I'm still looking into that as I think I set up the whole thing wrong. I'm thinking maybe I was supposed to keep some sort of logger file instead of the current User class, since making an object in my log in class doesn't really help me access the current user in my other classes. It's a work in progress.